# JavaScript Countdown with argument passing in

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

You are given an integer called start_num. Write a code that will countdown from start_num to 1, and when the countdown is finished, will print out "Liftoff!".

I am unsure how to do this and keep getting stuck.

This is the code I am provided with at the beginning of the problem:

```
    function liftoff_countdown(start_num) {
    // My code goes here!
    }
```

And then they want me to pass in a value such as the 5:

```
   liftoff_countdown(5);
```

And then this will be my output:

6

5

4

3

2

1

"Liftoff!"

Thanks!

Comment: Have you attempted to solve it? Do you have some code for the `liftoff_countdown` function?

Comment: Well, I used a for loop.such as for (i = start_num; start_num <= 1; i--);

Answer (score 1):

Look at this maybe help you to create your own code

make two file in a same folder (script.js and index.html)

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <title>Countdown</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
  <div id="inputArea">
  </div>
  <h1 id="time">0</h1>
</div> 
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var valueRemaining;
var intervalHandle;

function resetPage() {
  document.getElementById("inputArea").style.display = "block";
}

function tick() {
  var valueDisplay = document.getElementById("time");
  valueDisplay.innerHTML = valueRemaining;
  if (valueRemaining === 0) {
    valueDisplay.innerHTML = "Liftoff!";
    clearInterval(intervalHandle);
    resetPage();
  }
  valueRemaining--;
}

function startCountdown() {
  var count = document.getElementById("count").value;
  if (isNaN(count)) {
    alert("Please enter a number!");
    return;
  }
  valueRemaining =  count;
  intervalHandle = setInterval(tick, 1000);
  document.getElementById("inputArea").style.display = "none";
}

// as soon as the page is loaded...
window.onload =  function () {
  var inputValue = document.createElement("input");
  inputValue.setAttribute("id", "count");
  inputValue.setAttribute("type", "text");
  // create a button
  var startButton = document.createElement("input");
  startButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
  startButton.setAttribute("value", "Start Countdown");
  startButton.onclick = function () {
      startCountdown();
  };
  // add to the DOM, to the div called "inputArea"
  document.getElementById("inputArea").appendChild(inputValue);
  document.getElementById("inputArea").appendChild(startButton);
};
```

in this example you have many things to understand how javascript works behind scenes.

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

```js
function liftoff_countdown()
{
  var span=document.getElementById('num');
  var i=document.getElementById('num').innerText;
  i=i-1;
  span.innerText=i;
  if (i==0){
   span.innerText='Liftoff!';
   clearInterval(count_down)
  }
 
}
var count_down=setInterval(liftoff_countdown,1000);
```

```html
<span id="num">5</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a simple recursive function and the use of `setTimeout` to recursively call the function after a time lapse of `1 second`.

```
function lift_off(seconds) {
  if(seconds == 0) {
    console.log('liftoff');
  } else {
    console.log(seconds--);
    setTimeout(function(){lift_off(seconds);},1000);
  }
}

lift_off(10);
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m0vt3j3n/)

Answer (score 0):

**Preface**

A lot of these answers seem to be focused on doing things with timers and recursion. I do not believe that is your intent. If your only goal is to print those values to the console, you could simply do the following (see the comments for an explanation).

**The Answer**

```
function liftoff_countdown(start_num) {
    // Loops through all values between 0 and start_num
    for(int i = 0; i < start_num; i++) {
        // Prints the appropriate value by subtracting from start_num
        console.log( start_num - i );
    }
    // Upon exiting the loop, prints "Liftoff!"
    console.log("Liftoff!");
}
```

**Additional Thoughts**

You could just as easily loop backwards through the numbers instead of forward like so:

```
for(int i = start_num; i > 0; i--){
    console.log( i );
}
```

I tend to lean towards iterating forwards just because it's more common, and it's often easy to confuse readers of your code if they gloss over the loop initialization.

Additionally, I am working with the assumption that when you say "print" you mean "console.log()". If this is untrue, you could of course use any other function in its place (e.g. `alert( "Liftoff!" );`).